# Proving an $n\times n$ matrix is similar to its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Is proving that an $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrix $A$ is similar to $A^T$ different that proving that $A\sim A^T$ when $A$ is not $n \times n$ and diagonalizable?

I think I can work from $A=SDS^{-1}$ but I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For some $P$ and $Q$, one has $A=PDP^{-1}$ and $A^T=QDQ^{-1}$.

Solution: One has $D=P^{-1}AP=Q^{-1}A^TQ$. Thus
$$
A = PQ^{-1}A^TQP^{-1} = (PQ^{-1})\ A^T(PQ^{-1})^{-1}
$$

Comment: Ooh, so the $D$ in $A^T$ is the same as $D$ in $A$? How do we know that?

Comment: $A$ and $A^T$ have same set of eigen-values

Comment: @Mohammed-Khosravi Okay, that makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!